Can two objects of different mass experience the same air resistance?
This question is assuming that the objects have the same shape and size, but different masses. I know that all objects have the same gravitational acceleration on earth, which is about 9.8 m/s^2. Since air resistance depends largely on the square of an objects velocity, and they seem to be going the same speed due to the gravitational acceleration, wouldn't they both experience the same air resistance? Due to this,is only reason one would fall faster because there is a differing ratio between gravitational force and air resistance, as the force of gravity acts more strongly in the object with more mass? Thanks for the help and I hope this is worded well.

Does this answer your question? What would happen if you drop two objects of the same shape and size but different mass in Earth's atmosphere?

Terminal velocity is constant velocity. Constant velocity means zero acceleration. Zero acceleration means zero net force. Zero net force on a falling object means that air resistance pushing up exactly balances weight pulling down. Gravity pulls down harder on the heavier object—that's what "heavier" means—so air resistance must push up harder on it. Air resistance depends on shape and speed, but both objects have the same shape: Only speed matters. The terminal velocity of a heavy object must be greater than the terminal velocity of a lighter object if they both have the same shape. Q.E.D.

P.S., You said, and I echoed, "...same shape,..." but really I was picturing same shape, same size, same texture, and both falling in the same orientation.
